# Convert Normal Date to Timestamp

Tags: php, sql, forms, timestamp

How would I convert this user input:

> 01/22/2013 2:33 pm

into the normal SQL timestamp format using PHP?

> 2013-01-22 14:33:00

Comment: Google `php convert date to timestamp`

Comment: There is no normal SQL timestamp format. It's RDBMS and setting dependent... Are you trying to convert a string into a date? A PHP date or a SQL date?

Comment: Since this question has been closed, my answer is now a comment. You can use PHP's `strtotime` function to get it to UNIX Timestamp. Then `date()` to get to the format you want. `$time = strtotime('01/22/2013 2:33 pm'); $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp); echo $timestamp; //2013-01-22 14:33:00`

Comment: -1 FOR ABSOLUTELY 0 details to help us answer you question. Why is the user entering a random string? Use a datepicker + time control/inputs and validate it. Send the selected date as a unix timestamp (seconds, integer) or a ISO standard date format (ISO8601, 2011-12-05T12:34:56Z) to your application. What type has the field in your database? For text stuff (varchar, text, etc) put a standard ISO date in (not recommended). For DATETIME consult the respective database's docs. For INT put in a unix timestamp in seconds. See PHP docs for date time manipulation functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)'s [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:i a', '01/22/2013 2:33 pm');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```